# Optimize application performance when searching in the list

Tags: list, search, core-data, swiftui

How can I optimize the list filtering? There are 2000 records in the list and when entering text into the application's search engine it clips a bit. Do you have any suggestions that could optimize the search?

Code

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct SongbookView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Song.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Song.number, ascending: true)]
    ) var songs: FetchedResults<Song>
    
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                SearchBar(text: $searchText)
                Spacer()
                List(songs.filter({searchText.isEmpty ? true : removeNumber(str: $0.content!.lowercased()).contains(searchText.lowercased()) || String($0.number).contains(searchText)}), id:\.objectID) { song in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(song: song, isSelected: song.favorite)) {
                        HStack{
                            Text("\(String(song.number)). ") .font(.headline) + Text(song.title ?? "Brak tytułu")
                            if song.favorite {
                                Spacer()
                                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                                    .accessibility(label: Text("To jest ulubiona pieśń"))
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                            }
                        }.lineLimit(1)
                    }
                }.id(UUID())
            }
            .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Śpiewnik")
        }
    }
    func removeNumber(str: String) -> String {
        var result = str
        let vowels: Set<Character> = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
        result.removeAll(where: { vowels.contains($0) })
        return result
    }
}

extension UINavigationController {
    // Remove back button text
    open override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t use filter use nspredicate

Comment: To explicit the previous comment, try to apply the filtering (through a `NSPredicate`) on the fetch request itself. This would filter on fetching (optimized SQL request), avoiding loading 200 elements and then filter...

Comment: The song lyrics contain numbers that I am currently removing. Will this also be possible with this solution?  
`removeNumber(str:$0.content!.lowercased()).contains(searchText.lowercased())`